# Can't log in using WordPress.com OpenID

Tags: support, openid, login, wordpress-se

I can't seem to log back in to stackoverflow.com now on my Mac (I'm still logged in on my PC). I'm getting the following error message (my OpenID provider is WordPress.com):

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> The following required parameters were missing from the DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.CheckAuthenticationResponse message: is_valid

**Update:** I try logging out of WordPress.com, then logging back in to SO. WordPress.com asks me to sign in as usual, so I do it and refresh that page. And I get this:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Cannot decode Key-Value Form because a line was found without a ':' character. (line 3: '<head>')

I reload SO's login page and try logging in with my WordPress.com OpenID again. However many times I try that now, I no longer get the first error, only the second.

From the looks of the errors, they seem to be the ones slipping up. <del>Should I [report this issue to them](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact) too, just in case?</del> I've contacted them with a link to this question.

Just to add: I don't get automatically signed in to the main site even though I'm still logged into meta on my Mac, as well as a bunch of other Stack Exchange sites. I don't know if this has anything to do with the WordPress.com issue though.

Comment: that is odd, I would definitely open a support ticket on their end. We haven't changed anything in a long, long time.

Comment: @Jeff: yeah I just shot them a support mail at the same time you left the comment. I definitely think it's their fault more than ours.

Comment: `status-notourfault`?

Comment: Strange; I first noticed a problem Thursday night, and it was the same on Friday but with new error messages. I searched for questions both times (with the specific errors) but couldn't see anything relevant, so I posted [my own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76961/codereview-site-unable-to-register). Perhaps this question was not high enough on the list of results at that time. Can you add a `WordPress` tag to this question?

Comment: @Mark C: I've done that now.

Comment: Thanks. Please let us know when they contact you.

Comment: @Jeff @Bolt Ok, is their fault, but what can we do in the mean time to login?  Should we create a new openId and associate it with the existing?

Comment: @Oscar: That's what I'm thinking, but I'm lazy so I'll wait it out.

Comment: People, you can go to your profile, click in the "accounts" tab and click the link "add openid" in front of the "Registered User" title - and add a new OpenID. That is what I did to be able to comment here. Also, you all probably have more than one OpenID (or you do not have a Gmail account or Facebook profile? :) )

Comment: Doing this causes some mess with related accounts, though.

Comment: @brandizzi  We, certainly we can't do that, if we don't log in first right?

Comment: Now that they've fixed it, and it indeed is `status-notourfault`, perhaps it is time to close this as too localized :)

Comment: @Oscar well, you can do it if you have accounts in another Stack Excange site - although fortunately it is not possible :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've contacted the [WP support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/) and they said:

> We have corrected a glitch and the problem should no longer be occurring.

At least for me, it's working again.

Comment: Indeed they have, I've just received a reply as well and it's working for me again.

Comment: Same here, it was frustrating not being able to login here and add comments ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, its WordPress - they've changed something.  Leaving a comment on blogger.com doesn't work either.

Blogger.com reports:

> Your OpenID credentials could not be verified.

Comment: Yes i faced the same problem just now. But 2nd time it works. Don't know what is exactly happening :(

Answer (score 6):

Definitely looks like a problem on the WordPress end.  I repro the problem at http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx when entering my WordPress OpenID and get the same error.  Their OP Endpoint is broken.  The logs from test-id.org show they aren't handling OpenID associations nor are they responding correctly to the check_auth verification step.

Comment: Nice work. I got a reply from them last night - they say they're on it.